# Decomposition of an infinite set into pairwise disjoint subsets which exhaust set does not affect cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Show that if $X$ is an infinite set and $A$ is subset of the power set of $X$ containing only finite pairwise disjoint sets such that the union of all elements of $A$ is $X$, then cardinalities of $X$ and $A$ are equal.

Comment: That is an incredibly convoluted way of saying that if $S$ is a partition of $X$, whose elements are all finite, then $|S|=|X|$. In either case the axiom of choice is needed here; and what have you tried to do to prove this?

Comment: I didn't get any idea how to proceed as I was trying to prove it without axiom of choice. Now if axiom of choice is needed for this, let me try and I'll reply then.

Comment: By well ordering theorem I define order on X and S. Now I define function f: X to S as f(x) = least of(An)(with order of S) where An are in S and x is least element in An with same order as on X. Clearly f is 1-1. If I am able to find a 1-1 map from S to X also or onto map from X to S.(I am done because of Schorder Bernestein Theorem). Can you please give hint?

Comment: Use the axiom of *choice*.

Comment: Ok by another equivalent statement of AC: for every pairwise disjoint collection S of sets C there exist a set A such that A and C has intersection singleton. We can define a 1-1 map from S to X as this element for each set. Am I right?

Comment: Or just use the axiom of choice. *Directly*. Or just find an obvious map from $X$ onto $S$ (which exists without the axiom of choice).

Comment: Is there something wrong in my proof of finding 1-1 map from X to S as I didn't use finiteness of elements of S (which is very crucible as I can see)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your $f\colon X\to S$ is not defined on all $X$. You need to somehow extend it to all $X$, here's a hint: Remember that $|S|=|S\times\Bbb N|$.